# Emberjs dynamic segment: Error while loading route: TypeError {}

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get familiar with dynamic segment here. Here is what I want to achieve:

When i access '/#/inventories', it will list the inventory model in the 'inventories' template. This is done successfully.

When i click on the individual inventory id, it will access /#/inventories/1 be 1 is the inventory id, and it will fire up the 'inventory' template. This is done successfully as well.

However when i try to access /#/inventories/1 directly from the address bar, when i press F5, it comes out this error - `Error while loading route: TypeError {}`

The full list of error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
    var m = meta(this);
    m.proto = this;
    if (initMixins) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var mixins = initMixins;
      initMixins = null;
      this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
    }
    if (initProperties) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var props = initProperties;
      initProperties = null;

      var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

      for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
        var properties = props[i];

        Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

        for (var keyName in properties) {
          if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

          var value = properties[keyName],
              IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

          if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
            var bindings = m.bindings;
            if (!bindings) {
              bindings = m.bindings = {};
            } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
              bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
            }
            bindings[keyName] = value;
          }

          var desc = m.descs[keyName];

          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));

          if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
            var baseValue = this[keyName];

            if (baseValue) {
              if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
                value = baseValue.concat(value);
              } else {
                value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
              }
            } else {
              value = Ember.makeArray(value);
            }
          }

          if (desc) {
            desc.set(this, keyName, value);
          } else {
            if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
              this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
            } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
              Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
            } else {
              this[keyName] = value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    finishPartial(this, m);
    delete m.proto;
    finishChains(this);
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
} has no method 'find'
```

Here is my `app.js`:

```
Gymi = Ember.Application.create();

// Route map
Gymi.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('inventories', { path: '/inventories' }, function() {
        this.resource('inventory', { path: '/:inventory_id' });
    });
    this.resource('products');
});

// inventory models
Gymi.Inventory = Ember.Object.extend();
Gymi.Inventory.reopenClass({
    items: [],
    all: function() {
        this.items = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'item1',
            cost: '20.00',
            qty: 10
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'item2',
            cost: '20.00',
            qty: 10
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'item3',
            cost: '20.00',
            qty: 10
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: 'item4',
            cost: '20.00',
            qty: 10
        }];

        return this.items;
    }
})

// inventory controller
Gymi.InventoriesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    inventories: Gymi.Inventory.all()
});
```

Here is the templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<h2>{{title}}</h2>

<ul>
    <li>{{#linkTo 'inventories'}}Inventories{{/linkTo}}</li>
</ul>

{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="inventories">
<h2>Inventory</h2>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
{{#each inventory in inventories}}
    {{#with inventory}}
    <tr>
    <td>{{#linkTo 'inventory' inventory}}{{id}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{cost}}</td>
    <td>{{qty}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>

{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="inventory">
<h4>Inventory</h4>

<ul>
    <li>{{id}}</li>
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    <li>{{cost}}</li>
    <li>{{qty}}</li>
</ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for: But I think it's to do with Ember routing clicks/direct links differently. When you click a link to `/#/inventories/1` it will hijack that and just load the route anyway. It behaves differently when you go to that URL. If you are going by the RESTful way of naming URLs: You can just change the URL to `/#/inventory/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unhelpful error message, but the key part is at the end of it.

```
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
} has no method 'find'
```

When you visit the `/inventories/1` route, ember will try to lookup the record for that id, using `find`, in the `InventoryRoute`'s `model` hook. In this case on the `Inventory`. Since it can't find that method you get this error.

Adding an `Inventory.find` method that returns the record matching `params.inventory_id` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 14):

Not an answer to the OP but to all those who are getting the error after Sept 1, 2013, it might be due to the update of Ember Data to the latest 1.0 version. So you have to use

```
this.store.find('model');
```

Instead of

```
App.Model.find();
```

[Read more changes here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#defining-relationships-in-models).

Answer (score 1):

This error appears if your route is missing the parameter of the `model` method.

The following code works when visiting `/inventory/1` from a `link-to` **but not opening the page from the URL**:

```js
App.InventoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('inventory', params.inventory_id)
  }
});
```

Adding the missing `params` fixes. This code works both from a `link-to` and directly from the URL:

```js
App.InventoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.store.find('inventory', params.inventory_id)
  }
});
```

**For ember-data < 0.14 this is the code**

```js
App.InventoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    App.Inventory.find(params.inventory_id)
  }
});
```